# Name of this Java Swing component?

Tags: java, swing

[image: Old Advanced JPanel demo]

The above picture has a side panel type component that is perfect for what I need. Does anyone know what kind of component it is and where it is implemented from? I cannot find anything similar to the Swing documents. 
I understand this is an oracle demo which should give source code, however, all the links to the source code so far have been to the .net site which has since been closed.

Comment: In pure swing a JTree with all nodes expanded and not showing the root node, could be made to look like that.

Comment: Looks a `JTree` to me

Comment: I was under the impression that it may be a JTree, but it looks like a much more advanced version than in the documents so i was unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `JXTaskPaneContainer`and `JXTaskPane`

Go through following reference might help you

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=splash

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html